# How to fix Azure-CLI command az to Upload Universal Package using Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-artifacts

I am trying to run `az` command to upload a folder content as a Universal Package in Azure after my build pipeline. That is the last step.

I am trying to run the command below.

```sh
az artifacts universal publish \
    --organization "https://myamazingorganization.com" \
    --feed "my_favorite_feed" \
    --name "myupackage" \
    --version "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" \
    --description "My Universal Package" \
    --path <path_to_directory>
```

But after some messages of sucess like `Downloading Universal Packages tooling (ArtifactTool_linux-x64_0.2.101): 1.84%`, I am receiving the following error:

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

'module' object has no attribute 'uuid4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 603, in execute
    raise ex
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uuid4'
```

I am using `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`. To install Azure-CLI I am following the steps described at https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest .

My `az` version description is:

```
azure-cli                         2.0.70

command-modules-nspkg               2.0.3
core                              2.0.70
nspkg                              3.0.4
telemetry                          1.0.3

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.12.0

Python location '/bin/python'
Extensions directory '/home/azure/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2019, 20:27:34)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

How can I fix this issues in order to complete my release pipeline?

Comment: Do you mean that you deployed a self-hosted agent on CentOS and installed Azure-CLI on it? and then run the az command to publish the universal packages  in build/release pipeline with the self-hosted agent?

Comment: Thank you, Andi Li-MSFT. Yes, I did it.

Comment: There is temporary workaround, check whether it works or not https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/623

Comment: Thank you, starian chen-MSFT. But it was not useful for now.